# SwiftUI navigationLink isActivie not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Purpose**

My intention is to come back from view3 and return directly to view1

**Current Status**

My view hierarchy here is view1 -> view2 -> view3.

I use NavigationLink in view1 to open view2 and use Binding to pass a value to isActivie, then pass this value to view3, and when view3 is done, change the value passed to false and close view3 automatically.

But the result is that it stays in view2. Then the value passed in is equal to false

**Background and code**

```swift
// view 1 
@State private var detailViewIsShow: Bool = false

var body some: View {
    ForEach(boughtItems) { item in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ItemDetailView(item: item, detailViewIsShow: $detailViewIsShow),
                isActive: $detailViewIsShow
            ) {
                ItemCellView(item: item)
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        }
}

// view 2
@Binding var detailViewIsShow: Bool
@State var itemEditorViewIsShow: Bool = false

var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ItemEditorView(item: item, detailViewIsShow: $detailViewIsShow),
                isActive: self.$itemEditorViewIsShow
            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.itemEditorViewIsShow = true
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                })
            }
        }
    }

// view 3
@Binding var detailViewIsShow: Bool

struct body: some View {
someView()
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $isShowDeleteAlert) {
            Button("delete", role: .destructive) {
                item!.delete(context: context)
                self.detailViewIsShow = false
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What I know is - View1 should be holding NavigationView to have functionality similar to  popToRootViewController in your approach. Also in View3 why are you using both boolean navigation and presentationMode, thats incorrect I believe ?

Comment: Change `detailViewIsShow` to be a `selection` and use the `NavigationLink` with `tag` and `selection`. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Srivathsa presentationMode in View 3 is used to control the closing of view3, while the Binding in view3 is used to close view2

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you please give me a little example of what navigationLink with tag and selection means? @loremipsum

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:tag:selection:destination:)-510fq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add onChange() listener in view 2 on "detailViewIsShow" property and when it is false, dismiss current view

```
.onChange(of: detailViewIsShow) { newValue in
    if !newValue{
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: What you suggested will just dismiss the dialog. @IDTIMW wants to remove view3 and view2 from the stack, he is already removing the dialog upon clicking on the "DELETE" button.

Comment: Since "detailViewIsShow" is binded with view view 2 so it will automatically trigger onChange listener in view 2 when "self.detailViewIsShow = false" statement is executed and dismiss view 2 also

Comment: This solution worked, but still not very perfect, because the exit animation is first into view2, and then in the return to view1, my ideal solution is to go directly to view1, what better direction I can try? @FaizanYousaf

Comment: what if you remove the - 'presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()' from view3 ? Can you give a try and remove this line as onChange in view 2 dismisses view 2 and its subsequent views in the hierarchy.

Comment: If I remove 'presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()' in view3. After the delete operation is completed, it still stays at view2.  @Srivathsa

Comment: Yes you are correct, it has no effect and onChange listener also not getting called. Then this solution has 2 limitations - 1) double dismiss animation as you observed 2) if you introduce a new view - aView in between view2 & view3 then this solution will not work. If so then may be you should not accept this answer and wait for any better solutions ?